# Highcharts: How to draw a line on top of a column?

Tags: highcharts

I would like to have a line on top of the columns in a chart. The line is to show an estimated value while the column it self shows the actual value. I've tried to illustrate it with this image: http://i803.photobucket.com/albums/yy311/carlroger/chart3_zps50860449.png

The line will always be the same value for each year. Sometimes the line will be just a bit above and sometimes the column will exceed the line value.

Is it duable?

/Carl

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that in a two ways:

- use `columnrange` series: http://jsfiddle.net/zLC4Q/
- use `scatter` series with custom marker: http://jsfiddle.net/5Z386/